# Sass outputs default file even with changed variables

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, command-line, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change some variables for my custom version of Bootstrap. Right now I have the Bootstrap SCSS files and my own variables file. My file looks like this:

```
@import "/path/to/bootstrap";
$blue:    #42a5f5;
$indigo:  #5c6bc0;
more styles here…
```

However, when I run `sass /path/to/custom.scss /path/to/output.css`, it still outputs the default Bootstrap files like this:

```
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
more styles here…
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/):

> Variable overrides within the same Sass file can come before or after the default variables. However, when overriding across Sass files, your overrides must come **before** you import Bootstrap’s Sass files.

Since you create your own *custom.scss* file, it should look like this:

```
// Your variable overrides
$blue:    #42a5f5;
$indigo:  #5c6bc0;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "/path/to/bootstrap";
```